# Why does the page source of Facebook, unlike stack overflow, look the way it does?

Tags: html, css

Below are examples of the page source from both sites. I am on chrome if that means anything. My Questions is, why do these two sites look so differently from each other? Why does Facebooks source look the way it does, paragraphs and paragraphs of code with no formatting compared to stack overflow where tags and elements are distinguishable from each other?

Does it serve a purpose for it to be shown the way it looks on facebooks website? I assume that's not how it was formatted in development but done that way after loading it to the site?

****Here is an example of Facebooks source code from the landing page****

[image: Facebook Homepage Source Code]

****Here is an example of Stack Overflows source code from the landing page****

[image: Stack overflow Main Page Source Code]

Comment: Any feedback as to why this question is on hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. Majority of the code is on the server side anyway so you can't see majority of the code for both websites. However, Facebook's code has been minified. This means the code has been scrunched together to take up less space so that the site will load faster.

Comment: This makes sense, I though it may have been so people could not copy and dissect it easily.